# How can I make these tests more DRY?

Tags: perl, testing, dry, dancer

I currently have the following at the beginning of several test files, but it's very not DRY. But I'm not really sure what the best way to move this into its own file is. Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    use Test::More;
    use namespace::clean qw( pass );
}
use FindBin;
use Cwd qw( realpath );
use Dancer qw( :syntax );
use Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI;
set apphandler => 'PSGI';

my $appdir = realpath( "$FindBin::Bin/.." );
my $t = Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI->new(
    app => sub {
        my $env = shift;
        setting(
            appname => 'MyApp',
            appdir => $appdir,
        );
        load_app 'MyApp';
        config->{environment} = 'test';
        Dancer::Config->load;
        my $request = Dancer::Request->new( env => $env );
        Dancer->dance( $request );
    }
);
$t->agent('test');

$t->get_ok('/login') or diag $t->content;

$t->submit_form_ok({
    form_name =>'loginform',
    fields    => {
        username => 'myuser',
        password => 'foo',
    },
}, 'login ok' );

### END BOILERPLATE ###
```

**update**

unfortunately part of my problem with moving this off into a library is that as soon as I've done that the code stops working. I tried encapsulating it into a subroutine and returning `$t` but that doesn't appear to work. I'm trying to figure out what exactly needs to go into the library and what exactly needs to go into the test.

Comment: What does "stops working" mean?  What happens?  Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 2):

Make it a module (say `t::MyApp`), change `my $t` to `our $t`, and have the module export `$t`.  (You could also write a custom `import` method to turn on strict & warnings in your test script.)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `.pm` module that includes these lines, with some object-oriented code to obtain the `$t` and other information from the boilerplate code, and then `use` it from your tests.